# Luis MS Bot Framework - Response to prompt wrongly interpreted by Luis as Intent

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am creating a chatbot using Microsoft Bot Framework V4 with C#. I have also added a LUIS service in my chatbot.
There is a dialog flow using waterfall, which prompts users for few inputs eg. Date, Location, number of people etc.

The problem is that when the user replies suppose "Chicago" to Location, Luis calculates its intent  and it comes to Cancel or None.
Please let me know how to handle this situation.

Regards

Comment: Sorry your question seems too general to me. Could you add some scheme, code example or at least example of how data flows in happy day scenario of your solution and how should it behave but how it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

please share some more details of your code with us so that we can provide correct guidance. In your case I would suggest you to use a form flow dialog in your waterflow instead of a prompt dialog so that you can collect the data in one go and then make the LUIS call

Answer (score 0):

Is "Chicago" an intent or entity? If it's an entity (and it probably should be part of a location entity) that's normal. You just need to check for a location entity first. If you have an interrupt method that is getting called first, what I do is make the interrupt check for None or Cancel intents with *zero* entities given.